# Improving jQuery Mobile page render times

Tags: jquery-mobile, page-load-time, webpage-rendering

I have a jquery mobile page thats taking between 6-8 seconds to render on an iPhone 4.

The page load time seems okay and I've taken the necessary steps to optimise css, js etc. However, the page contains a number of form inputs that are rendered by jQM (ie. select dropdowns, sliders etc) and this seems to take about 4-5 seconds to render.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem and found a way to increase the render time?

I'm using the minimised jQM 1.0.

Thanks.

Comment: How big (ungzipped) is the JS code you're loading, phones only have small memory...

Answer (score 0):

Are all the .js and .css files needed at startup? I've found dynamically loading them after JQM initialized helped with initial perceived performance.

Also, do those form inputs need to be shown immediately on start? Maybe you could render them in the background and only in the pageshow event actually reveal their container...

Personally I had no such problems, so I would suggest you review your events firing and code logic - maybe there's a loop in there that's throwing you off.

Comment: There's actually very few js/css files but I've tried concatenating them and minifying but page load times didn't improve. Also, all the code is on a single HTML file but I don't think this affects rendering time as elements are rendered lazily on request.